# Jquery - Get DIV text with Class within Class

Tags: jquery

The following is the code for my `Headers` in a Grid. I want to iterate through the `div` class `ui-grid-cell-contents` which is within class `ui-grid-header-cell` to get all the column Headers & save it in an Array Object.

```
<div class="ui-grid-header-cell clearfix ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-002">
    <div class="ng-scope sortable">
        <div class="ui-grid-vertical-bar">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding" col-index="renderIndex">
            Code <span ui-grid-visible="col.sort.direction" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-icon-up-dir': col.sort.direction == asc, 'ui-grid-icon-down-dir': col.sort.direction == desc, 'ui-grid-icon-blank': !col.sort.direction }" class="ui-grid-icon-up-dir">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-column-menu-button ng-scope" ng-if="grid.options.enableColumnMenus &amp;&amp; !col.isRowHeader  &amp;&amp; col.colDef.enableColumnMenu !== false" ng-click="toggleMenu($event)"><i class="ui-grid-icon-angle-down">&nbsp;</i></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ui-grid-header-cell clearfix ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-002">
    <div class="ng-scope sortable">
        <div class="ui-grid-vertical-bar">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding" col-index="renderIndex">
            EMPLOYEE NAME<span ui-grid-visible="col.sort.direction" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-icon-up-dir': col.sort.direction == asc, 'ui-grid-icon-down-dir': col.sort.direction == desc, 'ui-grid-icon-blank': !col.sort.direction }" class="ui-grid-icon-up-dir">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-column-menu-button ng-scope" ng-if="grid.options.enableColumnMenus &amp;&amp; !col.isRowHeader  &amp;&amp; col.colDef.enableColumnMenu !== false" ng-click="toggleMenu($event)"><i class="ui-grid-icon-angle-down">&nbsp;</i></div>
    </div>
</div>

.......
```

I tried this :-

```
jq(".ui-grid-header-cell > .ui-grid-cell-contents").each(function (index, element) {
                    console.log(element);        
                });
```

Doesn't give expected results.

Comment: I want all the Header Names in an Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ui-grid-cell-contents` element is not a direct descendent of the `.ui-grid-header-cell`, although, it is a child. Simply omit `>` from your selector:

```
jq(".ui-grid-header-cell .ui-grid-cell-contents").each(function (index, element) {
    console.log(element);        
});
```

[Here's your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roayhua3/)

Comment: How to get the text within the div??

Comment: @anup `$(element).text();`